# create an object of <choice> group from a class that is automatically generated from Schema

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have a Schema and I generated a class (file.cs) out of that schema using xsd tool.
In the schema there is a choice group at the end that contains 3 nodes(records).

Among those 3 records I need to use one of them which is `<node2>`.
Here we are not using BizTalk maps or XSLT to map but we need to create an object of this class then serialize/deserialize, etc., etc., (this is the requirement).

Now the challenge is I have to access this `<node2>` from the Header because this `<choice>` group is under  record
Therefore in my C# code I'm able to get the `<Id>`and  fields from the `<header>`like

```
schema obj= new Schema();
Schema.Header= new Schema.Header();
Schema.header.Id="something"
Schema.header.name="something"
```

But for choice group Iam not able to access  from the header Record because its a Type of `<node1>`,`<node2>` and `<node3>`.But there is a class created for `<node2> which contains the field1 and field2.`

Can you please help me how do I access the  record from the Header?I need this for mapping.

For example (Schema.xsd)--->schema.cs file

```
   <Root>
<Header>
<Id></Id>
 <Name></name>
<choice>
 <node1>
```

```
<field2></field2>
<node2>
  <field1></field1>
<field2></field2>
<node3>
 <field1></field1>
 <field2></field2>
 </Header>
```

Comment: Sorry, your situation is not very clear.  What exactly do you mean by "not able to access from the header"?  You don't really access one node from another.

Comment: What I meant is there are 3 types node1,node2 and node3..my concern is about accessing the fields under node2ie field1 and field2..Can I just create an object of node2 class and access those fields? but is not that I have to get the node2 from Header like traversing from the root?

Answer (score 0):

If you generated your class using xsd.exe, then your header class should have a property called Item of type object. You can assign that property the object of either of Node1, Node2, or Node3 class.

Comment: Yes it has the item of type node1,2 and 3 but how can i access those fields ie field1 and field2...Do you mean to say something like create an object of that node2 class which is node2 nodeobj=new node2() and nodeobj.field1="" and nodeobj.field2=""..??

Comment: yes create first object of node2 and then use its property field1 and field2. once done assign this object to item property